# Join all items in 4 tables allowing nulls

Tags: sql, join, null, group-by

I'm working on a training program and I'm at a point where I can’t figure out the SQL query. 
I have 4 tables: userProfilesTbl, trainingTbl, userAssessmentTbl and setsTbl 
userProfilesTbl and userAssessmentsTbl are related through the UserId fkey which is a unique identity field type.

trainingTbl and userAssessmentTbl are related through the tt_id fkey INT field type. 
setsTbl and trainingTbl are related through the s_id fkey INT field type.

The trainingTbl is populated with training carried out on specified dates by specified user groups.

The userAssessmentTbl is populated by the individual users training (outcomes, notes etc).

The userProfilesTbl holds all additional user information not included in the membership and roles framework (connects to aspnet_users table).

The setsTbl is populated by a list of the different types of training.

I want to show all training sets and users regardless if they’ve done the training or not.

The Gridview (which is a PIVOT table) should be returning surName, from the userProfilesTbl, setName from the setsTbl and outcome (value) from the userAssessmentTbl.
At present I have 2 select statements

1. shows the setName and surname without any training outcomes

   `Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM userProfilesTbl LEFT OUTER JOIN userAssessmentTbl ON userProfilesTbl.UserId = userAssessmentTbl.UserId LEFT OUTER JOIN trainingTbl ON userAssessmentTbl.tt_id = trainingTbl.tt_id LEFT OUTER JOIN setsTbl ON trainingTbl.s_id = setsTbl.s_id WHERE  userProfilesTbl.st_id=@st_id AND userProfilesTbl.wa_id=@wa_id AND DATEPART(mm,t_date) = @m_date AND DATEPART(yyyy,t_date) = @y_date  ORDER BY surname ASC`
2. shows the training outcome setName, surname only of the users who have done the training and only the training they have carried out. All other users and training are not displayed.

   `SELECT * FROM userProfilesTbl, setsTbl, userAssessmentTbl, trainingTbl  WHERE (userProfilesTbl.UserId = userAssessmentTbl.UserId) AND (userAssessmentTbl.tt_id = trainingTbl.tt_id) AND userProfilesTbl.st_id=@st_id AND userProfilesTbl.wa_id=@wa_id AND DATEPART(mm,t_date) = @m_date AND DATEPART(yyyy,t_date) = @y_date  ORDER BY surname ASC`

I’m stumped any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Which database system do you use?
Many systems support `FULL OUTER JOIN` in addition to `LEFT`/`RIGHT OUTER JOIN`.
This returns records from both sides that have no partner on the other side.

EDIT:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM userProfilesTbl
  FULL OUTER JOIN userAssessmentTbl ON userProfilesTbl.UserId = userAssessmentTbl.UserId
  FULL OUTER JOIN trainingTbl ON userAssessmentTbl.tt_id = trainingTbl.tt_id
  FULL OUTER JOIN setsTbl ON trainingTbl.s_id = setsTbl.s_id
 ORDER BY surname ASC
```

should show you all data contained in your tables.
If you then restrict data using `WHERE`, you exclude also the rows having empty values in the column you use for the WHERE condition.

Hence, you should use something like

```
SELECT * 
  FROM userProfilesTbl
  FULL OUTER JOIN userAssessmentTbl ON userProfilesTbl.UserId = userAssessmentTbl.UserId
  FULL OUTER JOIN trainingTbl ON userAssessmentTbl.tt_id = trainingTbl.tt_id
  FULL OUTER JOIN setsTbl ON trainingTbl.s_id = setsTbl.s_id
 WHERE (userProfilesTbl.st_id=@st_id OR userProfilesTbl.st_id IS NULL)
   AND (userProfilesTbl.wa_id=@wa_id OR userProfilesTbl.wa_id IS NULL)
   AND ((DATEPART(mm,t_date) = @m_date AND DATEPART(yyyy,t_date) = @y_date) OR t_date IS NULL)
 ORDER BY surname ASC
```

Your second statement can probably be adapted similarly.

Comment: I'm using a Microsoft SQL Server (Express) database system. When i use FULL OUTER JOIN on the statements above the return is the same.

Comment: Did you also use `FULL OUTER JOIN`s on the second statement insterad of the `FROM`/`WHERE`? Also, you probably want to add something like `(userProfilesTbl.st_id=@st_id OR userProfilesTbl.st_id IS NULL)` to include those not matching.

Comment: Yes I've also used the FULL OUTER JOIN to no avail! The second part of your answer puts the IS NULL on the group st.id is say shop and wa_id is a shift. So therefore putting the IS NULL removes the means to filter the groups.

Comment: Trying to continue with this thread can anybody else assist please? Quite important!

Comment: Hi FrankPi i got you edited code above however this is incorrect!

Comment: Hi FrankPi I got your edited code above however this part below is incorrect! The WHERE (userProfilesTbl.st_id=@st_id OR userProfilesTbl.st_id IS NULL)
   AND (userProfilesTbl.wa_id=@wa_id OR userProfilesTbl.wa_id=@wa_id IS NULL) filters the shop and shift part of the training. Hhowever I need to show all the training available (setsTbl) regardless of the outcome also all the users in that shop and on that shift (userProfilesTbl) if they've done the training or not!  Right now its only showing users that have done training and training that's been done!

Comment: Sorry, this was a copy paste error of the expression. All conditions should read "`<some condition on column> or column is null`". I edited my answer accordingly. This is needed in order to keep the records that have null in these columns due to the FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Right the t_date IS NULL of you response led me to the string below! Sets show but still only shows users if they've done training. SELECT * FROM userProfilesTbl LEFT OUTER JOIN userAssessmentTbl ON userProfilesTbl.UserId = userAssessmentTbl.UserId FULL OUTER JOIN trainingTbl ON userAssessmentTbl.tt_id = trainingTbl.tt_id RIGHT OUTER JOIN setsTbl ON trainingTbl.s_id = setsTbl.s_id  WHERE userProfilesTbl.st_id=@st_id  AND  userProfilesTbl.wa_id=@wa_id AND (DATEPART(mm,t_date) = @m_date AND DATEPART(yyyy,t_date) = @y_date) OR t_date IS NULL ORDER BY setName ASC, t_date ASC, surname ASC

Comment: If you use a LEFT OUTER JOIN and not a FULL OUTER JOIN, you will not get all users profiles.

Comment: I have used LEFT OUTER JOIN and get the same thing! When the users (userProfileTbl.UserId) has no value/record in (userAssessmentTbl.UserId) even if they're in the shop/shift the user completely disappears (from header)! I need them to be visible at all time! similar to the sets! Infuriating!

Comment: Then use `FULL` OUTER JOIN (as I had proposed from the beginning).

Comment: NO sorry that doesn't work! This is the closest I've got SELECT * FROM userProfilesTbl LEFT OUTER JOIN userAssessmentTbl ON userProfilesTbl.UserId = userAssessmentTbl.UserId LEFT OUTER JOIN trainingTbl ON userAssessmentTbl.tt_id = trainingTbl.tt_id RIGHT OUTER JOIN setsTbl ON trainingTbl.s_id = setsTbl.s_id  WHERE userProfilesTbl.st_id=@st_id  AND  userProfilesTbl.wa_id=@wa_id AND (DATEPART(mm,t_date) = @m_date AND DATEPART(yyyy,t_date) = @y_date) OR t_date IS NULL ORDER BY setName ASC, t_date ASC, surname ASC Think its clashing somewhere on the userAssessmentTbl Thanks anyway

Comment: Can anybody else assist me? The code above works I just need the users from the userProfilesTbl who are in a particular shop (userProfilesTbl.st_id) and in a particular shift (userProfilesTbl.wa_id) to be visible regardless if they've not done the training! Every month I filter by date to see who's done the training.  It will show if you've done training but the user disappears if they've done no training for that month.